# normalizing features for classification

Tags: matlab

I am trying to normalize my image object features for classification purposes using z-score. Unfortunately, the normalized features for all objects seem to be the same. What would be the problem and how can it be rectified? The portion of the algorithm is given below.

```
% FEATURE EXTRACTION

cc = bwconncomp(ROI, 8) % connected components in ROI of binary image



for i = 1:Number_objects  




Number_objects = cc.NumObjects % number of connected components

imagecomponents = regionprops(cc,'Area','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Perimeter',...
'EquivDiameter','Extent','Orientation','Solidity','Eccentricity')

Areas = imagecomponents(i).Area

MajorAxisLengths = imagecomponents(i).MajorAxisLength

MinorAxisLengths = imagecomponents(i).MinorAxisLength

Perimeters = imagecomponents(i).Perimeter

EquivDiameters = imagecomponents(i).EquivDiameter

Extents = imagecomponents(i).Extent

Orientations = imagecomponents(i).Orientation

Soliditys = imagecomponents(i).Solidity

Eccentricitys = imagecomponents(i).Eccentricity

end

Areas_vector = [imagecomponents.Area]'

MajorAxisLengths_vector = [imagecomponents.MajorAxisLength]'

MinorAxisLengths_vector = [imagecomponents.MinorAxisLength]'

Perimeters_vector = [imagecomponents.Perimeter]'

EquivDiameters_vector = [imagecomponents.EquivDiameter]'

Extents_vector = [imagecomponents.Extent;]'

Orientations_vector = [imagecomponents.Orientation]'

Soliditys_vector = [imagecomponents.Solidity]'

Eccentricitys_vector = [imagecomponents.Eccentricity]'

% NORMALIZATION OF FEATURES 


Areas_mean = mean(Areas_vector);

MajorAxisLengths_mean = mean(MajorAxisLengths_vector);

MinorAxisLengths_mean = mean(MinorAxisLengths_vector);

Perimeters_mean = mean(Perimeters_vector);

EquivDiameters_mean = mean(EquivDiameters_vector);

Extents_mean = mean(Extents_vector);

Orientations_mean = mean(Orientations_vector);

Soliditys_mean = mean(Soliditys_vector);

Eccentricitys_mean = mean(Eccentricitys_vector);

%compute the standard deviations of features

Areas_std = std(Areas_vector),y = std(Areas_vector')

MajorAxisLengths_std = std(MajorAxisLengths_vector);

MinorAxisLengths_std = std(MinorAxisLengths_vector);

Perimeters_std = std(Perimeters_vector);

EquivDiameters_std = std(EquivDiameters_vector);

Extents_std = std(Extents_vector);

Orientations_std = std(Orientations_vector);

Soliditys_std = std(Soliditys_vector);

Eccentricitys_std = std(Eccentricitys_vector);

%normalization

for i = 1:Number_objects
Normalized_Areas(i) = (Areas - Areas_mean)/Areas_std

Normalized_MajorAxisLengths(i) = (MajorAxisLengths - MajorAxisLengths_mean)/MajorAxisLengths_std

Normalized_MinorAxisLengths(i) = (MinorAxisLengths - MinorAxisLengths_mean)/MinorAxisLengths_std

Normalized_Perimeters(i) = (Perimeters - Perimeters_mean)/Perimeters_std

Normalized_EquivDiameters(i) = (EquivDiameters - EquivDiameters_mean)/EquivDiameters_std

Normalized_Extents(i) = (Extents - Extents_mean)/Extents_std

Normalized_Orientations(i) = (Orientations - Orientations_mean)/Orientations_std

Normalized_Soliditys(i) = (Soliditys - Soliditys_mean)/Soliditys_std

Normalized_Eccentricitys(i) = (Eccentricitys - Eccentricitys_mean)/Eccentricitys_std

end

for i = 1:Number_objects
Normalized_Areas_vector = Normalized_Areas'
Normalized_MajorAxisLengths_vector = Normalized_MajorAxisLengths'
Normalized_MinorAxisLengths_vector = Normalized_MinorAxisLengths'
Normalized_Perimeters_vector = Normalized_Perimeters'
Normalized_EquivDiameters_vector = Normalized_EquivDiameters'
Normalized_Extents_vector = Normalized_Extents'
Normalized_Orientations_vector = Normalized_Orientations'
Normalized_Soliditys_vector = Normalized_Soliditys'
Normalized_Eccentricitys_vector = Normalized_Eccentricitys'          
end


Components_matrix = [Normalized_Areas_vector Normalized_MajorAxisLengths_vector Normalized_MinorAxisLengths_vector Normalized_Perimeters_vector...
Normalized_EquivDiameters_vector Normalized_Extents_vector Normalized_Orientations_vector Normalized_Soliditys_vector Normalized_Eccentricitys_vector]

Mean_Components_vector = mean(Components_matrix)'
```

Lastly, i would like each object to (return) have a different name e.g. Normalized_object_vector1, Normalized_object_vector2, etc. How can I do that in Matlab? Please help.

Comment: I removed the verbose output of your post.  It distracts us from your actual issue and it makes your post harder to read.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "normalized features for all objects seem to be the same" Please give examples of your objects, and your normalized features, and an explanation as to why you think they should be different.

Comment: @John The data was removed in the edit. You can see it if you look at the edit history, but be warned it's very, as rayryeng put it, verbose ;)

Comment: The objects are vehicle blobs. I would like to attach the image with the blobs but unfortunately, my reputation points do not allow. I think they should be different because if they are all equal in magnitude, then how can you tell which one is which? Kindly also consider my second question. Thanks in advance.